# MySQL error after increasing innodb buffer pool

Tags: mysql, innodb

I increased the buffer pool for mysql innodb and I got this error.

Now mysql wouldn't even start.

This happened when I restarted my computer and mysql still had problems. I am working on OSX and can't find my my.cnf either.

```
$ mysqld -uroot -p

2017-01-11T11:17:14.127290Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-01-11T11:17:14.128286Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.128917Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13) starting as process 2014 ...
2017-01-11T11:17:14.139702Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2017-01-11T11:17:14.140644Z 0 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

2017-01-11T11:17:14.148026Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-11T11:17:14.148056Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-01-11T11:17:14.148060Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-01-11T11:17:14.148064Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-01-11T11:17:14.149318Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-01-11T11:17:14.150616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-01-11T11:17:14.153003Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-01-11T11:17:14.165811Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-11T11:17:14.187092Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.247127Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-01-11T11:17:14.247345Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-01-11T11:17:14.261446Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.262167Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.262177Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.264859Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-01-11T11:17:14.319034Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.13 started; log sequence number 1991037762
2017-01-11T11:17:14.319286Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-01-11T11:17:14.320610Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.325376Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327107Z 0 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '-p'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327131Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-01-11T11:17:14.327143Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327361Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327372Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327376Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327378Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327380Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327419Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327444Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327449Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327453Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327456Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327460Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327464Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327472Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327479Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327482Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327485Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327489Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327493Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327496Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327500Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327503Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327507Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327510Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327514Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327543Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327556Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327561Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327566Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327570Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327574Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327581Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327585Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327590Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327595Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327641Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327773Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170111 17:02:14
2017-01-11T11:17:14.327836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-01-11T11:17:14.328161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170111 17:02:14
2017-01-11T11:17:15.780219Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1991037781
2017-01-11T11:17:15.781632Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-01-11T11:17:15.781739Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-01-11T11:17:15.781747Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-01-11T11:17:15.781752Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-01-11T11:17:15.781756Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-01-11T11:17:15.781958Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-01-11T11:17:15.782174Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just upgrade?  You probably failed to run `mysql_upgrade`.

Comment: Got this error: 
````mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server````

Comment: What was the previous version?  If it was before 5.6, then you probably have to step through the major versions.

Comment: I was not doing an upgrade. I just changed the innodb_buffer_size

Comment: Can't connect on sock -- usually means you are trying to connect remotely.